# Hebrew source for a question in "Guidelines" chanukah edition by Rabbis Jaeger and Barclay

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, jewish-books, chanuka, menora-chanukia

For someone who has the sefer "Guidelines" Chanukah Edition by Rabbis Jaeger and Barclay, can you tell me which sources they list in the back of the sefer for the question, "The branches of the menorah should not be very close to one another since each light should be separated from the next by 2 cm. If the lights are too close to each other they will appear like a torch, which is not valid. (According to some opinions, a menorah does not appear like a torch and no minimum separation is required.)"   Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So for background the quote can be found in Chapter 2 on pages 19-20, no. 24.

The notes at the back read as follows:

> מ"ב  ס' תרעא ס"ק יח, מבית לוי להגר"ש ואזנר ח"י עמ' יג

And the sources are as follows:

[Mishnah Berurah 671:18](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.671.18?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> מאחר שכל נר מובדל הרבה וכו' - משמע מלשון זה דתרתי בעינן דהיינו שיהיו ג"כ מובדלים הקנים אחד מחבירו לבד מה שיש לכל קנה מחיצה בפני עצמה ועיין בא"ר שכתב דדי ברחב אצבע. וה"ה כשמדבקין נרות שעוה בכותל יראה שיהיו מרווח אחד מחבירו עכ"פ כשיעור אצבע

[MiBeis Levi 10 p. 13](https://tablet.otzar.org/#/book/52318/p/21/t/9680613531234/fs/0/start/0/end/0/c):

> וכל זה בנרות שעוה שאינם מונחים במנורה, אבל בנרות המונחים במנורה שהקנים בשוה, אין צריך הפרש אצבע בין קנה לקנה ובין שלהבת לשלהבת, וכן שמעתי ממרן שליט"א, ופשוט.

Comment: Thanks a lot man.

Comment: Pleasure! @tomelpora